# Azure policy to create locks on all vm's in a subscription

Tags: azure, locking, policy, azure-policy

I am using this code below to attempt to lock just the VM's in a subscription, but the effect is to place a lock on the Resource Groups.  How can I make this apply only to vm's only and not the RG?

```
{
"properties": {
  "displayName": "All Azure Vm's should be Delete Locked",

  "mode": "Indexed",
  "description": "This policy will add an CanNotDelete Resource Lock.",
  "metadata": {
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "category": "Compute"
  },
"parameters": {
"effect" : {
 "type" : "String",
 "metadata" : {
  "displayName" : "Effect",
  "description" : "Enable a Delete Lock" 
 },
 "allowedValues" : [
    "CanNotDelete",
    "ReadOnly",
    "NotSpecified" 
 ],
 "defaultValue": "CanNotDelete"   
}
},
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "field": "type",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
                }
               
            ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "auditIfNotExists",
            "details": {
                "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks",
                
                "existenceCondition": {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks/level",
                    "equals": "CanNotDelete"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Created a policy to place locks on Virtual machines in Azure.  Locks are placed on the Resource Group, which does lock the vm, but I only want the lock on the vm and not the resource group.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the deployment part of `deployment` template.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/pattern-deploy-resources#deployment-template

You can only assign the `resource lock` on a single resource, if you do not want to assign it on the `resource group`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/scope-extension-resources?tabs=azure-cli#apply-to-resource

For a single resource `resource lock`, then you need to use and define a `scope`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/lock-resources?tabs=json#template

Under the `"resources": [` you can do multiple deployments, see code #2:

#1

```
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "All Azure Vm's should be Delete Locked",
        "description": "This policy will add an CanNotDelete Resource Lock.",
        "mode": "all",
        "metadata": {
            "version": "1.1.0",
            "category": "Compute"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "effect": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Effect",
                    "description": "Enable a Delete Lock"
                },
                "allowedValues": [
                    "CanNotDelete",
                    "ReadOnly",
                    "NotSpecified"
                ],
                "defaultValue": "CanNotDelete"
            }
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "DeployIfNotExists",
                "details": {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks",
                    "existenceCondition": {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks/level",
                        "equals": "[parameters('effect')]"
                    },
                    "roleDefinitionIds": [
                        "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635"
                    ],
                    "deployment": {
                        "properties": {
                            "mode": "incremental",
                            "template": {
                                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
                                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                                "parameters": {},
                                "variables": {
                                    "vmName": "vm-niclas01"
                                },
                                "resources": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks",
                                        "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
                                        "name": "DenyDelete",
                                        "scope": "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "level": "CanNotDelete",
                                            "notes": "Prevents deletion of resource."
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#2 - Deploy lock on multiple VMs, not on RG:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Test 2 - All Azure Vm's should be Delete Locked",
        "policyType": "Custom",
        "mode": "All",
        "metadata": {
            "version": "1.1.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "effect": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "Effect",
                    "description": "Enable a Delete Lock"
                },
                "allowedValues": [
                    "CanNotDelete",
                    "ReadOnly",
                    "NotSpecified"
                ],
                "defaultValue": "CanNotDelete"
            },
            "vmName": {
                "type": "Array",
                "metadata": {
                    "displayName": "VM Names",
                    "description": "The list of VM names that should have resource locks"
                },
                "allowedValues": [
                    "vm-niclas01",
                    "vm-niclas02",
                    "vm-linuxniclas"
                ]
            }
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "in": "[parameters('vmName')]"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "DeployIfNotExists",
                "details": {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks",
                    "existenceCondition": {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks/level",
                        "equals": "[parameters('effect')]"
                    },
                    "roleDefinitionIds": [
                        "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/8e3af657-a8ff-443c-a75c-2fe8c4bcb635"
                    ],
                    "deployment": {
                        "properties": {
                            "mode": "incremental",
                            "template": {
                                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
                                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "vmName": {
                                        "type": "Array"
                                    }
                                },
                                "variables": {
                                    "vmName1": "[concat('/', parameters('vmName')[0])]",
                                    "vmName2": "[concat('/', parameters('vmName')[1])]"
                                },
                                "resources": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks",
                                        "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
                                        "name": "DenyDelete",
                                        "scope": "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', variables('vmName1'))]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "level": "CanNotDelete",
                                            "notes": "Prevents deletion of resource."
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/locks",
                                        "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
                                        "name": "DenyDelete",
                                        "scope": "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName2'))]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "level": "CanNotDelete",
                                            "notes": "Prevents deletion of resource."
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "outputs": {}
                            },
                            "parameters": {
                                "vmName": {
                                    "value": "[parameters('vmName')]"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3 VMs in the same RG:
[image]

Policy assignment with parameter:
[image]

Resource Lock deployed:
[image]

Resource Lock not deployed, because it is not part of policy parameter:
[image]